# Undefined property when unit testing my discord.js bot (the test itself is passed, but it is followed by an error)

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, bots, discord.js

I am trying to set up unit testing for my discord.js bot, but when running `npm test` in the terminal, while the test is being passed, still gives an error.

This is an image of the test being passed followed by the error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnpKc.png

I need to fix this error in testing, while still having the bot being able to function.

I have tried to completely remove the line referenced in the error (and the lines that had something to do with that specific line)

```
  jsfiles.forEach((f, i) => {
    let props = require(`./cmds/${f}`)
    bot.commands.set(props.help.name, props)
  })
```

Removing this resolved the testing issue, but resulted in the bot not functioning correctly (it did not load the commands; meaning, the bot couldn't be interacted with), which is not the goal here.

I've also checked, that each of the files in the folder `cmds` ends with

```
module.exports.help = {
  name: '<name of the command I use for each command>'
}
```

This is the part of my `bot.js` file that contains the problem.

```
// Loads the commands for the bot:
fs.readdir('./cmds/', (err, files) => {
  if (err) console.error(err)

  let jsfiles = files.filter(f => f.split('.').pop() === 'js')
  if (jsfiles.length <= 0) {
    console.log('No commands to load!')
    return
  }

  if (testingSettings) {
    console.log(`Loading ${jsfiles.length} commands!`)
  }

  // This is the problem referenced above: 
  // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  jsfiles.forEach((f, i) => {
    let props = require(`./cmds/${f}`)
    bot.commands.set(props.help.name, props)
  })
  // ----------------------------------------------------------------------

})
```

This is all of my code in the `bot.test.js` file

```
const { 
  // Functions
  checkingTesting,

  // Variables
  testingSettings,
} = require('./bot')


test('checking to see if testing-mode is on', () => {
  expect(checkingTesting(testingSettings, 'token')).toBe(process.env['token']);
});
```

If it is needed. This is the function, variable and exporting method that is used to connect `bot.js` to `bot.test.js`:

Variable (in `bot.js` file)

```
const testingSettings = false
```

Function (in `bot.js` file)

```
function checkingTesting (testingSettings, name) {
  if (testingSettings) {
    return testSettings[name]
  } else if (!testingSettings) {
    return process.env[name]
  }  
}
```

Exporting (in `bot.js` file)

```
module.exports = {
  // Exporting functions
  checkingTesting: checkingTesting,


  // Exporting variables
  testingSettings: testingSettings,
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`props.help` is undefined. The required file's exported obj is either empty, doesn't have `help`, or some other unforeseen event.

A good practice is to always check whether an object key exist prior using it.

```
if (props && props.help) {
    bot.commands.set(props.help.name, props)
} else {
    //throw or handle error here
}
```

Comment: With this code I can run the test without error. I would like to know, what I could put in the else-statement, as I cannot console.log when testing. Thanks btw

Comment: Instead of ignoring the error, you should make sure each file has what you expect in it. If you don't even know what your own code does, how can you ever hope to test it?

Comment: @AndreasG.DPetersen Sorry fella. I haven't used jest. But try this: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2441
Some people had success with console.log. Others didn't have. Would probably be for the best if you find a "debug" solution u can use together with jest.

Comment: @JoshyRobot
First, no one stated to ignore the error. The else case explicitly states to handle the error. Be it log event, exit process, whatever the dev decides upon.
Secondly, "you should make sure each file has what you expect in it", which he stated in his OP: "I've also checked, that each of the files in the folder cmds ends with module.exports.help".
Third, don't ever expect your input to work as intended! Do always check and handle the else case as best suited.

Answer (score 1):

In your command file, it seems like there is no `help` property of `module.exports`. When you try to read `help.name`, it throws your error because `help` is undefined.

Check to make sure that you're declaring `module.exports.help` in every command file.

Comment: I checked each file, and all of them has this

```
module.exports.help = {
  name: '<name of the command I use for each command>'

}
```
I tried to remove all files in the `cmds` folder. It worked, but only because this code:
```
let jsfiles = files.filter(f => f.split('.').pop() === 'js')
  if (jsfiles.length <= 0) {
    // console.log('No commands to load!')
    return
  }
```
stops the rest of the run from getting to this
```
bot.commands.set(props.help.name, props)
```

Comment: Did you check *every* single file in `./cmds/`?

Comment: Yes, and now I also double checked that it is the case

Comment: Log `props` to the console.

Comment: This is an image of the console.log of `props` when running the bot normally (`node bot.js`)
https://i.imgur.com/BawYgcP.png

It is not possible to console.log things in the `bot.js` file after testing
https://i.imgur.com/0ZHwUZj.png

Comment: Does this only occur during testing?

Comment: Yes, it only occurs during testing